# Connecting 2 different api to one react application with axios

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux

I have an existing api which I am using to get data to my react application, however, I created a new api which I want to connect to the react app. Wondering what is the solution to get data from 2 separated api on the same time? 
I have a base url as it below:

````
  let sessionToken = localStorage.getItem('currentUser.sessionToken')
  axios.defaults.baseURL = urls.baseUrl(url),
  if (sessionToken) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Token token=${sessionToken}`
  }
}```
````

Comment: When asking questions please reference guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, can you add some additional context to this question please.  When you say at the same time time, do you mean in parallel?

Comment: updated. Yes, I want to fetch from 2 different apis at the same time or depending on the call.